Numba, Neat, Numpy error: RuntimeError: Call parameter type does not match function signature
I am using numba with neat-python and numpy.
Somehow I get the error: RuntimeError: Call parameter type does not match function signature!
It was working well before. I have included relevant code below. The function calculate_forces is a function of the class which is at the top of the code.
The for loop in the third chunk of code is in a different file, where the evaluation of the genome takes place.
The error message is extremely long, but one of the things it underlines is the call:
cell.calculate_forces(cell.Fmax*Fext)
There must be a mistake here. I think it has to do with maybe an interaction of numpy and numba.
I really need help with this. Hope someone can throw some light.
spec = [
('number_of_beads', int32),               # a simple scalar field
('number_of_dimensions', int32),               # a simple scalar field
('bead_radius', float32[:]),               # a simple scalar field
('eta', int32),               # a simple scalar field
('L0', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('Lmin1', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('Lmax1', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('Lmin2', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('Lmax2', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('L', float32[:,:]),          # an array field
('V', float32[:,:]),          # an array field
('F0', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('Fmax', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('t0', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('ts', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('k', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('nint', int32),               # a simple scalar field
('teuler', float32),               # a simple scalar field
('tint', float32),
('Lambda', float32)]               # a simple scalar field
@jitclass(spec)
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, eta, current_nint, Lcilia, Lmax2Multiplier, Rb, Rc):
        self.number_of_beads=3
        self.number_of_dimensions=2
        self.bead_radius=np.array([Rb, Rc, Rc],dtype=float32)
        self.eta=eta
        self.L0=10


def calculate_forces(self, Fext):
    restoring_forces=self.calculate_restoring_forces()
    Ftot=np.zeros((self.number_of_beads,self.number_of_beads,self.number_of_dimensions))
    for i in range(self.number_of_beads):
        for j in range(self.number_of_beads):           
            Ftot[i,j,:]=(Fext[i,j]+restoring_forces[i,j])*self.calculate_normalized_positions()[i,j,:]
    return Ftot, restoring_forces


for i in range(N):
    Fext=np.zeros((cell.number_of_beads,cell.number_of_beads),dtype=np.float32)
    .
    .
    .
    L=np.array([L12,L13,L23])
    if i%cell.nint==0:
        f = net.activate(L/cell.L0)
    
    Fext[0,1]=f[0]
    .
    .
    .
    Ftot, restoring_forces = cell.calculate_forces(cell.Fmax*Fext)


the error we get is SyntaxError: '[' was never closed, so your bug is that you are missing the spec list closing bracket. anything more involved than that you need to create a [mcve]

That bracket is actually closed in my code. I just made a mistake while copying. OK I have to see if I can create a minimal reproducible example. Because the code is much longer.
